# in git-svn, how do I change the svn branch that a git branch is tracking?

Tags: git, branch, git-svn

My normal git-svn workflow is to do my work on a local branch, then merge to master and `git svn dcommit` from there to record my commits onto the svn trunk.

However, in my current local branch (`foo`) I'm realizing that this work is going to be around for a while before I feel comfortable committing it to the trunk, and other developers might be involved in it before then. I would like to "back it" by a svn branch, so that my work is on the server.

I've created a new svn branch (`svnFoo`) from the current trunk and I basically want to "move" `foo` so that when I `svn dcommit` from it all of its commits get recorded on `svnFoo` instead of `trunk`.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rebase` is your friend here. Assuming you created the local `foo` branch from the local `master` branch, and you've done a recent `git svn fetch` so your local Git repository knows about the remote `svnFoo` branch, the magic command you want is this:

```
git rebase --onto remotes/svnFoo $(git merge-base master foo) foo
```

This will find the commit where you branched `foo` from `master`, and replay all the commits from there to the head of the `foo` branch on top of the `svnFoo` branch. Subsequent `git svn dcommit`s will commit onto the Subversion `svnFoo` branch rather than the trunk.